# Is there any sharp style in CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, photoshop

I want to style some fonts in my css using the style- sharp found in Photoshop. Does anyone know the way?

Comment: You mean "antialias setting" sharp? I think you're out of luck in CSS there.

Comment: Perhaps one of the Flash based font replacement techniques can do something *similar*? Just a guess.

Comment: Based on everyone's comments I would then have to say that it's the designers responsibility to not use Sharp and instead find a more achievable approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Photoshop uses a custom font rendering engine which you won't be able to emulate using CSS. Furthermore, each platform has its own rendering engine which CSS cannot control.

For WebKit there is `-webkit-font-smoothing` but what it does is a far cry from what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's a browser/os combination that decides how your fonts are anti-aliased. Nothing you can do about it, except save the Photoshop output as an image, set it as a background for whichever container your text appears in and apply a negative text indent on it via css.

Answer (score 0):

No luck I'm afraid. The only way I know of (perhaps someone knows otherwise) to achieve this is to save the text in question as an image. Fine for headings etc., but not for body text.

Answer (score 0):

The "sharpness" of a font is usually a thing of the font renderer which is part of the operating system. You should check the font settings. In Windows, for example, try turning off [ClearType](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/cleartypeinfo.mspx).

Answer (score 0):

There is solution for font smoothing.

You can use `cufon.js` to render your font sharply & smoothly. This js renders your text as a cufon and if you right click on it it shows image. You can use this for heading.