# How to sharp the text in css3?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any sharp style in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003816/is-there-any-sharp-style-in-css)

Is there any way to do text sharp style in css3? In my design, the text is sharp! But when I coded it to HTML/CSS, exact style is not getting. Is there anyway to give text sharp style in css3?

Comment: you must explain a little bit more detailed what exactly your problem is. What kind of design? Are you talking about a graphical text and wondering that a written text doesn't look exactly the same?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique (or 2) to give certain fonts in webkit browsers a little "extra" sharpness. Chris Coyer has an article [here](http://css-tricks.com/beefing-up-dull-text-in-webkit/)